# Spring boot seems could not find mybatis mapper configurations(Mapped Statements collection does not contain value)

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am working with mybatis and spring-boot.

I have been suffered for several hours with follow message.

```
2018-02-18 15:25:13.774 ERROR 77556 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for org.owls.mybatis.mapper.TestMapper.selectTimestamp
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for org.owls.mybatis.mapper.TestMapper.selectTimestamp] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for org.owls.mybatis.mapper.TestMapper.selectTimestamp
```

My source is based on [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)(Spring boot get started with project) and add Mybatis settings.

I think somehow mybatis could not find the mapper information, So I would like to print registered mybatis mapper list in the console. (Is it possible?)

FYI, follow is the things I implemented.

I uses `application.yml` to add mybatis

```
mybatis:
    type-aliases-package: org.owls.mybatis.model
    type-handlers-package: org.owls.mybatis.handler
    mapper-locations: classpath:/resources/mybatis/mapper/*_mapper.xml 
    configuration:
        map-underscore-to-camel-case: true
        default-fetch-size: 100
        default-statement-timeout: 30
```

And this is `/resources/mybatis/mapper/test_mapper.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="org.owls.mybatis.mapper.TestMapper">
    <select id="selectTimestamp" resultType="map">
        SELECT NOW() FROM DUAL
    </select>
</mapper>
```

From here is Java codes.

First, Mapper interface `TestMapper` which in `org.owls.mybatis.mapper` package is

```
public interface TestMapper {
    @Select("SELECT NOW() FROM DUAL")
    public Map selectTimestamp() throws Exception;
}
```

Second, I made a Service which generate `SqlSessionTemplate`. Here is the code

```
@Service
public class MybatisService implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MybatisService.class);
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    DBService dbService;


    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }


    // Register a Object with a name, if not exists
    private void registerBean(String beanName, Object newBean){
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry)  context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(newBean.getClass());
        BeanDefinition def = builder.getBeanDefinition();
        if(!registry.containsBeanDefinition(beanName)) registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, def);
    }


    /*
    * Managing SqlSessionFactory
    * */
    private SqlSessionFactory generateSqlSessionFactory(String dsId, DataSource ds) throws Exception {
        String beanName = dsId + "SqlSessionFactory";

        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = null;
        try {
            Object registeredBean = context.getBean(beanName);
            logger.info("Found SqlSessionFactory bean [ " + beanName + " ]. Returns the instance");
            sqlSessionFactory = (SqlSessionFactory) registeredBean;
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
            logger.info("Not found SqlSessionFactory bean [ " + beanName + " ]. Generate new one");
            SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
            sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(ds);
            sqlSessionFactory = (SqlSessionFactory) sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
            registerBean(beanName, sqlSessionFactory);
        }
        return sqlSessionFactory;
    }


    /*
    * Managing SqlSessionTemplate
    * */
    private SqlSessionTemplate generateSqlSessionTemplate(String dsId, SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) throws Exception {
        String beanName = dsId + "SqlSessionTemplate";
        SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate = null;
        try {
            Object registeredBean = context.getBean(beanName);
            logger.info("Found SqlSessionTemplate bean [ " + beanName + " ]. Returns the instance");
            sqlSessionTemplate = (SqlSessionTemplate) registeredBean;
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
            logger.info("Not found SqlSessionTemplate bean [ " + beanName + " ]. Generate new one");
            sqlSessionTemplate = new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
            registerBean(beanName, sqlSessionFactory);
        }
        return sqlSessionTemplate;
    }


    public SqlSessionTemplate getSqlSessionTemplate(String dsId) {
        SqlSessionTemplate template = null;
        try {
            DataSource ds = dbService.getDS(dsId);
            SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = generateSqlSessionFactory(dsId, ds);
            template = generateSqlSessionTemplate(dsId, sqlSessionFactory);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to fetch SqlSessionFactory. returns null value ", e);
        }
        return template;
    }
}
```

Finally, in the Controller, I call it with ...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/test"})
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    MybatisService mybatisService;
    private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        sqlSessionTemplate = mybatisService.getSqlSessionTemplate("test");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"getCurrentTimestamp"})
    public @ResponseBody String getCurrentTimestamp() throws Exception {

        logger.info("=== SqlSessionTemplate Info in Controller :: " + sqlSessionTemplate);

        Map<String, Object> data = (Map) sqlSessionTemplate.selectOne("org.owls.mybatis.mapper.TestMapper.selectTimestamp");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
    }
};
```

I think the error message is little bit vague. (I could not find any clue which is wrong among settings - `mapper xml`, `application.yml`, `db connection`)

Thanks for answers.
[Access full source code](https://bitbucket.org/juneyoung/mybatistest)

======================== Edit #1. 19 FEB =============================

I found it out that `SqlSessionFactory` `Configuration` does not have any mapper at all.

I could print mapper list via follow way. 
In code where generates `SqlSessionFactory` ...

```
// FOR TEST 0219
MapperRegistry registry = sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().getMapperRegistry();


logger.info("=== Printing Mapper Registry starts");
registry.getMappers().forEach(mapper -> {
    logger.info("Mapper Registry :: " +  mapper.getName());
});
logger.info("=== Printing Mapper Registry ends");
// FOR TEST 0219
```

In my case, it prints nothing, but it is able to add mapper or package through `MapperRegistry` instance.

Here is what I thought

1. `SqlSessionFactory`(provided by ibatis) requires `DataSource`
2. `SqlSessionTemplate`(provided by ibatis) is endpoint and it requires `SqlSessionFactory`
3. In conclusion, `SqlSessionTemplate` depends on `SqlSessionFactory` which depends on `DataSource`.

If so, how could I properly generate `SqlSession*` as bean in a project which uses dynamic Datasource?

In my upper code(edited one), I was able to add mapper as bean but every `SqlSessionFactory` has same Mappers(duplicated, since `MapperRegistry` get a package name as a parameter)

How could I set different mappers to corresponding `SqlSessionFactory`?